# How to delete Kafka brokers machines from kafka cluster

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-zookeeper

We have Kafka cluster , cluster include **7** Kafka brokers ,

Version details:

```
Kafka machines are installed on rhel version 7.2 
Kafka version is 0.1x
Zookeeper version: 3.4.10
schema-registry version: 4.0.0
```

Each Kafka broker machine include the following services

```
Kafka broker
Zookeeper server
Schema registry
```

Now we want to delete `2 Kafka` brokers machines from the current Kafka cluster ( the  Kafka machines that we want to delete are – `06/07` ( Kafka version – `0.1X` , )

So cluster should be finally with:

`5 Kafka` brokers machines - `kafka01, kafka02 , kafka03 , kafka04 , kakfa05 , kafka05`

`3 zookeeper` servers/services that installed on `kafka01, kafka02 , kafka03`

`5 schema registry` services that installed on  `kafka01, kafka02 , kafka03 , kakfa05 , kafka05`

We are not sure what are exactly the configuration files in Kafka brokers that should be changed,  when we delete from the cluster the Kafka brokers - `kafka 07/06`

***I will happy to get remarks/notes about Kafka brokers deletion procedure***

from my understanding we need to do the following in order to remove the kafka machines - `kafka 06/07`

on `kafka06/07`

stop the services of

```
Kafka broker
Zookeeper server
Schema registry
```

then shutdown the `kafka06/07` machines as

```
init 0
```

then restart the following service on `kafka01/02/03/04/05`

```
Kafka broker
Zookeeper server
Schema registry
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To remove a Kafka Broker component, first identify and reassign the Kafka topic partition Leaders from the Kafka Broker, that you want to decommission, by using the kafka-reassign-partitions.sh script, and then shutdown the Kafka Broker service.

And remove the host from the bootstrap-servers in producers and consumers.

Comment: I dont understand why we need to do the kafka-reassign-partitions.sh , as I know when we add kafka to the cluster then you are right the need to do the reassign-partitions , in order to move the data from the topic to the new kafka , but in our case we delete the kafka06/07 from the cluster , maybe you mean that - after we stop the services Kafka broker
Zookeeper server
Schema registry on kafka06/07  , only then we need to do the Kafka-reassign-partitions , in order to update the leader to be only kafka01-05  ------ am I correct here ?

Comment: Zookeeper holds the metadata of topics and it’s leaders. If you don’t reassign, how will it ever change the replicas to other nodes. Also leader will switch if there is an ISR. If not then it will fail for that topic-partition. For the ones with ISR, leader will change to existing one but how will it zookeeper know that Kafka06 is decommissioned. Without reassign, it will keep that partition in under-replicated forever. Hence reassign is recommended if you want to decommission it properly. If not, it will be treated as broker down state.

Comment: It should be BEFORE STOPPING THE SERVICE. Before you take any broker down, neither consumer and producer should be talking to it nor any inter-broker communication(like replication). That means no topic-partition should be residing on the broker, only then you should bring the broker down. Also, make sure your controller is stable during these operations.

Comment: sorry but still not make sense to perform the reassign before stop the kafka , its more logical when stooping the service kafka on kafka06/07 and then do the  reassign , I am say that because what we achive when we do the reassign before stop the kafka  . if all brokers id's are balanced and kafka is stable ?

Comment: Stopping and reassigning doesn’t even make sense. Please go through documentation of kafka again. I have decommissioned many brokers by this way. If you want to do it the wrong way, go ahead and try. Once the service is down, then no communication can be made with that service then how can you even reassign? If you have 1RF for a partition and is on Kafka06/07, then how will you reassign if you bring them down. There is no way to even access the broker then how will you get the data?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220152/discussion-between-jessica-and-suman).

Comment: you said "first identify and reassign the Kafka topic partition Leaders from the Kafka Broker" , as you know  reassign should be on one kafka machine in the cluster not necessary it should be kafka06/07 , am I right ?

Comment: I have commented in discussion chat box.